# File uploaded in a folder depending on the file name and extension. Jquery/blueimp - plugin

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui, zend-framework, upload

I would kindly ask all of you if you could help me. I'm working in zend framework and I need to adjust my code so, when a user
drops the file in the browser(before the actual upload), the file name and extension is checked in a sense if it already exists. Depending on the existence of the ifle, an
icon right by the trash icon will appear (green tick if fresh upload, no other file with the same name. Red cross if there is a file).

But to address a matter that is more important to me, and that is for me to set up the code in a manner so when uploading depending on the file name and file extension, the file is being uploaded in a specific folder. So e.g. an X.png, gets into a "png" folder - subfolder "X", and Y.pdf gets into a "pdf" folder - subfolder "Y"

Here is my code do far...

This is the application.js and the jquery.fileupload-ui.js. (javascript)
http://pastebin.com/eqpK1KmX

This is the index.phtml and the layout of the index.phtml (view)
http://pastebin.com/mh5jnLju

InterfaceController.php (controller):

```
<?php
class Design_InterfaceController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
    public function init()
    {
        $this->_helper->layout()->setLayout('media');
        set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
        realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/modules/design/models'),
        realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/models'),
        realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library'),
        get_include_path(),
        )));
    }

    public function indexAction()
    { 

    }

    public function mediaAction()
    {
    $this->_helper->layout()->setLayout('media');

    }

    public function checkFile(){



        //isn't doing anything at all, just my start of thinking in a way of
            //sloving this


    }

    function uploadjqAction()
    { 
    $this->_helper->layout()->setLayout('media');
            Zend_Loader::loadClass('Upload',
                                    array(
                                        APPLICATION_PATH.'/modules/design/models/vendors'
                                    )
            );


        $upload_handler = new Upload();

        header('Pragma: no-cache');
        header('Cache-Control: private, no-cache');
        header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="files.json"');
        header('X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff');

        switch ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) {
            case 'HEAD':
            case 'GET':
                $upload_handler->get();
                break;
            case 'POST':
                $upload_handler->post();
                break;
            case 'DELETE':
                $upload_handler->delete();
                break;
            case 'OPTIONS':
                break;
            default:
                header('HTTP/1.0 405 Method Not Allowed');
        }
        exit;

    }






}
```

This is the upload.php (acting as a model):

```
<?php
/*
 * Copyright 2010, Sebastian Tschan
 * https://blueimp.net
 *
 * Licensed under the MIT license:
 * http://creativecommons.org/licenses/MIT/
 */

error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);

class Upload
{
    /*  public function uploadAction() {
        ini_set("max_execution_time", 10000);
        $this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();
        $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true);
            if (!empty($_FILES)) {
            $tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
            $targetPath = STORAGE_PATH.'/books/' . $_POST['bookid'] . '/' . $_POST['folder'];
            $targetFile =  str_replace('//','/',$targetPath) . "/".$_POST['name'].".".$_POST['ext'];
            if (!file_exists(str_replace('//','/',$targetPath))) mkdir(str_replace('//','/',$targetPath), 0755, true);
            $result = move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);
            echo ($result)?"Success":"Fail";
        }
    }
 */
    private $options;

    function __construct($options=null) {
        $this->options = array(
            'script_url' => $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],
            'upload_dir' => dirname(__FILE__).'/vendors/files/',
            'upload_url' => dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']).'/vendors/files/',
            'param_name' => 'files',
            // The php.ini settings upload_max_filesize and post_max_size
            // take precedence over the following max_file_size setting:
            'max_file_size' => 10000000,
            'min_file_size' => 1,
            'accept_file_types' =>'/(\.|\/)(gif|jpeg|jpg|png|pdf)$/i',
            'max_number_of_files' => null,
            'discard_aborted_uploads' => true,
            'image_versions' => array(
                'thumbnail' => array(
                    'upload_dir' => dirname(__FILE__).'/vendors/thumbnails/',
                    'upload_url' => dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']).'/vendors/thumbnails/',
                    'max_width' => 80,
                    'max_height' => 150
                )
            )
        );
        if ($options) {
            $this->options = array_replace_recursive($this->options, $options);
        }
    }

    private function get_file_object($file_name) {
        $file_path = $this->options['upload_dir'].$file_name;
        if (is_file($file_path) && $file_name[0] !== '.') {
            $file = new stdClass();
            $file->name = $file_name;
            $file->size = filesize($file_path);
            $file->url = $this->options['upload_url'].rawurlencode($file->name);
            foreach($this->options['image_versions'] as $version => $options) {
                if (is_file($options['upload_dir'].$file_name)) {
                    $file->{$version.'_url'} = $options['upload_url']
                        .rawurlencode($file->name);
                }
            }
            $file->delete_url = $this->options['script_url']
                .'?file='.rawurlencode($file->name);
            $file->delete_type = 'DELETE';
            return $file;
        }
        return null;
    }

    private function get_file_objects() {
        return array_values(array_filter(array_map(
            array($this, 'get_file_object'),
            scandir($this->options['upload_dir'])
        )));
    }

    private function create_scaled_image($file_name, $options) {
        $file_path = $this->options['upload_dir'].$file_name;
        $new_file_path = $options['upload_dir'].$file_name;
        list($img_width, $img_height) = @getimagesize($file_path);
        if (!$img_width || !$img_height) {
            return false;
        }
        $scale = min(
            $options['max_width'] / $img_width,
            $options['max_height'] / $img_height
        );
        if ($scale > 1) {
            $scale = 1;
        }
        $new_width = $img_width * $scale;
        $new_height = $img_height * $scale;
        $new_img = @imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
        switch (strtolower(substr(strrchr($file_name, '.'), 1))) {
            case 'jpg':
            case 'jpeg':
                $src_img = @imagecreatefromjpeg($file_path);
                $write_image = 'imagejpeg';
                break;
            case 'gif':
                @imagecolortransparent($new_img, @imagecolorallocate($new_img, 0, 0, 0));
                $src_img = @imagecreatefromgif($file_path);
                $write_image = 'imagegif';
                break;
            case 'png':
                @imagecolortransparent($new_img, @imagecolorallocate($new_img, 0, 0, 0));
                @imagealphablending($new_img, false);
                @imagesavealpha($new_img, true);
                $src_img = @imagecreatefrompng($file_path);
                $write_image = 'imagepng';
                break;
            default:
                $src_img = $image_method = null;
        }
        $success = $src_img && @imagecopyresampled(
            $new_img,
            $src_img,
            0, 0, 0, 0,
            $new_width,
            $new_height,
            $img_width,
            $img_height
        ) && $write_image($new_img, $new_file_path);
        // Free up memory (imagedestroy does not delete files):
        @imagedestroy($src_img);
        @imagedestroy($new_img);
        return $success;
    }

    private function has_error($uploaded_file, $file, $error) {
        if ($error) {
            return $error;
        }
        if (!preg_match($this->options['accept_file_types'], $file->name)) {
            return 'acceptFileTypes';
        }
        if ($uploaded_file && is_uploaded_file($uploaded_file)) {
            $file_size = filesize($uploaded_file);
        } else {
            $file_size = $_SERVER['CONTENT_LENGTH'];
        }
        if ($this->options['max_file_size'] && (
                $file_size > $this->options['max_file_size'] ||
                $file->size > $this->options['max_file_size'])
            ) {
            return 'maxFileSize';
        }
        if ($this->options['min_file_size'] &&
            $file_size < $this->options['min_file_size']) {
            return 'minFileSize';
        }
        if (is_int($this->options['max_number_of_files']) && (
                count($this->get_file_objects()) >= $this->options['max_number_of_files'])
            ) {
            return 'maxNumberOfFiles';
        }
        return $error;
    }

    private function handle_file_upload($uploaded_file, $name, $size, $type, $error) {
        $file = new stdClass();
        // Remove path information and dots around the filename, to prevent uploading
        // into different directories or replacing hidden system files.
        // Also remove control characters and spaces (\x00..\x20) around the filename:
        $file->name = trim(basename(stripslashes($name)), ".\x00..\x20");
        $file->size = intval($size);
        $file->type = $type;
        $error = $this->has_error($uploaded_file, $file, $error);
        if (!$error && $file->name) {
            $file_path = $this->options['upload_dir'].$file->name;
            $append_file = !$this->options['discard_aborted_uploads'] &&
                is_file($file_path) && $file->size > filesize($file_path);
            clearstatcache();
            if ($uploaded_file && is_uploaded_file($uploaded_file)) {
                // multipart/formdata uploads (POST method uploads)
                if ($append_file) {
                    file_put_contents(
                        $file_path,
                        fopen($uploaded_file, 'r'),
                        FILE_APPEND
                    );
                } else {
                    move_uploaded_file($uploaded_file, $file_path);
                }
            } else {
                // Non-multipart uploads (PUT method support)
                file_put_contents(
                    $file_path,
                    fopen('php://input', 'r'),
                    $append_file ? FILE_APPEND : 0
                );
            }
            $file_size = filesize($file_path);
            if ($file_size === $file->size) {
                $file->url = $this->options['upload_url'].rawurlencode($file->name);
                foreach($this->options['image_versions'] as $version => $options) {
                    if ($this->create_scaled_image($file->name, $options)) {
                        $file->{$version.'_url'} = $options['upload_url']
                            .rawurlencode($file->name);
                    }
                }
            } else if ($this->options['discard_aborted_uploads']) {
                unlink($file_path);
                $file->error = 'abort';
            }
            $file->size = $file_size;
            $file->delete_url = $this->options['script_url']
                .'?file='.rawurlencode($file->name);
            $file->delete_type = 'DELETE';
        } else {
            $file->error = $error;
        }
        return $file;
    }

    public function get() {
        $file_name = isset($_REQUEST['file']) ?
            basename(stripslashes($_REQUEST['file'])) : null; 
        if ($file_name) {
            $info = $this->get_file_object($file_name);
        } else {
            $info = $this->get_file_objects();
        }
        header('Content-type: application/json');
        echo json_encode($info);
    }

    public function post() {
        $upload = isset($_FILES[$this->options['param_name']]) ?
            $_FILES[$this->options['param_name']] : array(
                'tmp_name' => null,
                'name' => null,
                'size' => null,
                'type' => null,
                'error' => null
            );
        $info = array();
        if (is_array($upload['tmp_name'])) {
            foreach ($upload['tmp_name'] as $index => $value) {
                $info[] = $this->handle_file_upload(
                    $upload['tmp_name'][$index],
                    isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILE_NAME']) ?
                        $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILE_NAME'] : $upload['name'][$index],
                    isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILE_SIZE']) ?
                        $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILE_SIZE'] : $upload['size'][$index],
                    isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILE_TYPE']) ?
                        $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILE_TYPE'] : $upload['type'][$index],
                    $upload['error'][$index]
                );
            }
        } else {
            $info[] = $this->handle_file_upload(
                $upload['tmp_name'],
                isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILE_NAME']) ?
                    $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILE_NAME'] : $upload['name'],
                isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILE_SIZE']) ?
                    $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILE_SIZE'] : $upload['size'],
                isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILE_TYPE']) ?
                    $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILE_TYPE'] : $upload['type'],
                $upload['error']
            );
        }
        header('Vary: Accept');
        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT']) &&
            (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT'], 'application/json') !== false)) {
            header('Content-type: application/json');
        } else {
            header('Content-type: text/plain');
        }
        echo json_encode($info);
    }

    public function delete() {
        $file_name = isset($_REQUEST['file']) ?
            basename(stripslashes($_REQUEST['file'])) : null;
        $file_path = $this->options['upload_dir'].$file_name;
        $success = is_file($file_path) && $file_name[0] !== '.' && unlink($file_path);
        if ($success) {
            foreach($this->options['image_versions'] as $version => $options) {
                $file = $options['upload_dir'].$file_name;
                if (is_file($file)) {
                    unlink($file);
                }
            }
        }
        header('Content-type: application/json');
        echo json_encode($success);
    }
}

?>
```

If anyone is willing to help, I would be very very grateful, I know it a lot of work, I'm a noob and I need all the help I can get.

Thank you in advance! and please don't get mad at me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few general comments.

Typically, the `include_path` setting is done at Bootstrap, not in the controller.

I would clearly separate in my mind what happens on the server side and what happens on the client side.

First, think of it first as a standard form submission. The form has a file element, the user browses his file system to select his file. He clicks submit. It either succeeds or fails. All the dragging and dropping and changing icons is pure client-side candy to be added after you have the core functionality in place.

So, I would create a form that has a standard file element. To that element, I would attach a custom validator that performs your specific directory/filename checks. In the event of a valid submission, you employ a model/service that moves the file to the right place, writes your db records, etc.

Then I would layer on some AJAX handling. Client-side script intercepts the form's submit event and you use an AjaxContext action helper on the server side to send back JSON responses. These responses are handled by client-side code that renders your ok/fail icons.

Finally, I would layer on the client-side drag/drop functionality to trigger the submit event.

The benefits:

1. It clearly delineate server-side and client-side issues.
2. It breaks the overall job into a targeted collection of well-defined tasks.
3. Progressive enhancement/graceful degradation.
4. Seems more consistent with the ZF way of handling form submissions in controllers (create form with validators, check isValid(), process successful submission).

I recognize that this is only broad brush-strokes, but I hope it helps to clarify some thinking.