# Drag and drop feature of sorting my categories

Tags: php, zend-framework, kohana

I use kohana in my e-commerce application.

I have a catalogue of categories.

I want to find the module in the box with drag and drop feature to sort my categories. Does  anybody know some **php** scripts, modules based on Kohana, Zend, etc.?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/8076886/131824 for some general thoughts for this type of thing.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/dynamic-dragn-drop-with-jquery-and-php/

**FYI: Code in the above link uses foreach loop to update each record, that is resource consuming...**

```
foreach ($updateRecordsArray as $recordIDValue) {
    $query = "UPDATE records SET recordListingID = " . $listingCounter . " 
             WHERE recordID = " . $recordIDValue;
    mysql_query($query) or die('Error, insert query failed');
    $listingCounter = $listingCounter + 1;
}
```

**You can use a reliable code like this:**

```
$casesSql = '';
$idValues = array();
foreach ($order as $orderNum => $idValue) {
    $casesSql .= " WHEN '" . $idValue . "' THEN '" . ($orderNum + 1) . "'";
    $idValues[] = $idValue;
}

$sql = "UPDATE `" . $table . "`"
        . " SET `DisplayOrder` = CASE `" . $idField . "`"
        . $casesSql . " END"
        . " WHERE `" . $idField . "` IN (" . implode(', ', $idValues) . ")";
```

*Which uses only one query to update whole records that are to be updated, where $order is something like:*

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 4
    [3] => 3
)
```